# Break statement not storing data, returns only last value input

Tags: java, class, loops, break

My break statement below works perfectly fine. There are no errors. However, when I enter multiple values for multiple products, it only returns data for the last product entered. For example, if I input productNum = 1 and numSold = 5, then productNum = 2, then numSold = 5; it will only calculate totalSales for productNum = 2 and only track return a value numSold = 5. It will "forget" the data for productNum = 1 and its numSold.

I want it to store data for numSold1 thru numSold5, and also continue to add values to totalSales. Can anyone please point in the right direction for this?

Here's my sales calculator:

```
public class SalesCalculator {

    private int productNum, numSold, numSold1, numSold2, numSold3, numSold4, numSold5;

    private double price1 = 2.98, price2 = 4.50, price3 = 9.98, price4 = 4.49, price5 = 6.87, totalSales = 0.00;

    public int setProductNum(int productNum) {

        this.productNum = productNum;
        return productNum;
    }

    public int setNumSold(int numSold) {

        this.numSold = numSold;
        return numSold;
    }

    public double calculateSales() {

            switch (productNum) {

                case 1:
                    totalSales += (price1 * numSold); // multiplies how much of this product was sold by its price and adds to overall sales
                    numSold1 += numSold; // tracks how much of this product was sold of this product
                    break;

                case 2:
                    totalSales += (price2 * numSold);
                    numSold2 += numSold;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    totalSales += (price3 * numSold);
                    numSold3 += numSold;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    totalSales += (price4 * numSold);
                    numSold4 += numSold;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    totalSales += (price5 * numSold);
                    numSold5 += numSold;
                    break;

                // default just breaks out of loop in case invalid product number entered
                default:
                    break;
            }

        return totalSales;
    }

public double getTotalSales() { return totalSales; }

public int getNumSold1() { return numSold1; }
public int getNumSold2() { return numSold2; }
public int getNumSold3() { return numSold3; }
public int getNumSold4() { return numSold4; }
public int getNumSold5() { return numSold5; }

// get prices, included because i wasn't sure if assignment required them or not
public double getPrice1() { return price1; }
public double getPrice2() { return price2; }
public double getPrice3() { return price3; }
public double getPrice4() { return price4; }
public double getPrice5() { return price5; }
}
```

Here's what takes the input:

```
public class SalesCalculatorTest {

public static void main(String[] args){

    SalesCalculator salesCalculator1 = new SalesCalculator();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int calcSales;

    do {

        System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the product number, then press ENTER.\n");
        int productNum = input.nextInt();
        salesCalculator1.setProductNum(productNum);

        System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the quantity sold, then press ENTER.\n");
        int numSold = input.nextInt();
        salesCalculator1.setNumSold(numSold);

        System.out.printf("\nType -1 to calculate sales. Press ENTER to input more data.\n");
        calcSales = input.nextInt();
        } while (calcSales != -1);

    if (calcSales == -1) {

        salesCalculator1.calculateSales();
    }

    double totalSales = salesCalculator1.getTotalSales();
    System.out.printf("\nTotal sales for products sold was $%.2f", totalSales);

    int numSold1 = salesCalculator1.getNumSold1();
    double price1 = salesCalculator1.getPrice1();
    System.out.printf("\n\nProduct 1 sold %d units at $%.2f each", numSold1, price1);

    int numSold2 = salesCalculator1.getNumSold2();
    double price2 = salesCalculator1.getPrice2();
    System.out.printf("\nProduct 2 sold %d units at $%.2f each", numSold2, price2);

    int numSold3 = salesCalculator1.getNumSold3();
    double price3 = salesCalculator1.getPrice3();
    System.out.printf("\nProduct 3 sold %d units at $%.2f each", numSold3, price3);

    int numSold4 = salesCalculator1.getNumSold4();
    double price4 = salesCalculator1.getPrice4();
    System.out.printf("\nProduct 4 sold %d units at $%.2f each", numSold4, price4);

    int numSold5 = salesCalculator1.getNumSold5();
    double price5 = salesCalculator1.getPrice5();
    System.out.printf("\nProduct 5 sold %d units at $%.2f each\n", numSold5, price5);
}
}
```

Comment: `calculateSales()` uses the field `productNum` to determine which `case` is executed, and `productNum` will be whatever the last product number input was as this is set via `setProductNum(int)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the way you have designed your program, you need to call `calculateSales()` after each pair of calls to `setProductNum()` and `setNumSold()`.

Therefore the following line needs to be within your `do ... while` loop:

```
salesCalculator1.calculateSales();
```

The reason for this is that `productNum` and `numSold` are over-written with each pair of calls to `setProductNum()` and `setNumSold()`. Therefore you need to use these values while they are current. Otherwise, as you note, all your calculations will use the last set values, ie. the earlier values are "forgotten".

Comment: That is almost exactly what I did. I actually ended up passing productNum and numSold directly into calculateSale(), and did away with setProductNum() and setNumSold(). Big thanks to you and d.j.brown for the hints!! I'd buy you guys dinner if I knew you in IRL

Comment: @JakeDoe Happy to help and your new design sounds like a big improvement. Feel free to upvote and/or select this answer if you found it helpful :)